# Scikit-learn's dump_svmlight_file slow

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, libsvm

Dumping a 10,000 x 40,000 CSR matrix with about 5 million non-zero elements into /dev/null took about 6 minutes. Is there a faster alternative?

Converting it to another sparse format did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Ignore the following answer! There is actually a [Cython based dumper](https://github.com/mblondel/svmlight-loader) by the authors of  the scikit-learn implementation. It can dump the same matrix in 3 seconds.

The following runs in 60 seconds, 6 of which spend outside the loop. It takes advantage of the fact that a COO matrix is essentially in the right format already.

```
def dump_svmlight_file_sparse(X, y, f, zero_based=True):
    X = X.sorted_indices().tocoo()

    if not zero_based:
        X.col += 1

    y = y.astype(int).astype(str)
    col = X.col.astype(str)
    dat = X.data.astype(str)

    last_row = 0
    f.write(y[0])

    for i in xrange(len(X.data)):
        while last_row < X.row[i]:
            last_row += 1
            f.write('\n'+y[last_row])

        f.write(' '+col[i]+':'+dat[i])

    f.write('\n')
```

Comment: Actually I forgot about this one, but the core of the function is written in C++, not Cython.

Answer (score 2):

The [current implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/8861833ec9ee67656670af66605991c44207ff81/sklearn/datasets/svmlight_format.py#L230) is quite naive in 0.14. You can try to profile it with [line_profiler](http://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/) to find the main bottleneck.

If you find a faster way to implement it (optionally using cython as for the loader), then please feel free to open a pull request.

Comment: Ok, I made some progress (see my answer). I think I will write the code to dump a sorted coo matrix in C.

Answer (score 2):

If you upgrade to the bleeding-edge development version of scikit-learn (or copy-paste [this file](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ad15405f3c6f7d298fbf5ae5a5391532ae4f0e9d/sklearn/datasets/svmlight_format.py) into your installation), you'll get a `dump_svmlight_file` that's about ten times faster than before.